# How to customize the "Date" from Advanced Custom Field

Tags: wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields

I need to make an agenda for a website in Wordpress. 
I use ACF for the date and I would like to separate the day, month and year with a span or a div to change the style of the date.

For the moment I have :

```
<?php the_field('jour_de_levenement'); ?>
```

The date appears but I can't select the day to customize it. So I tried something like that but it didn't seem to work :

```
<?php $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dFY', get_field('jour_de_levenement')); ?>
<span class="day"><?php echo $date->format('d'); ?></span>
<span class="month"><?php echo $date->format('F'); ?></span>
<span class="year"><?php echo $date->format('Y'); ?></span>
```

It gives me a fatal error.

Here an image of what I want to do : 
[date-agenda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts0ez.jpg)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ACF documentation here:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/

I came up with this code, using your information:

```
<?php // get raw date
$date = get_field('jour_de_levenement', false, false);
// make date object
$date = new DateTime($date); ?>
<span class="day"><?php echo $date->format('d'); ?></span>
<span class="month"><?php echo $date->format('F'); ?></span>
<span class="year"><?php echo $date->format('Y'); ?></span>
```

When testing this code, I made a date field with all of the settings at their defaults (specifically the Display Format and Return Format options). The second false in the get_field() elminates the need for most of the code in your createFromFormat function.